# Would my code really take 8 years or so to decipher

Tags: c#, .net, security, cryptography

While reading the Hashing topic of C# in a nutshell book,i came across the following quotes!

> You can provide additional protection against dictionary attack by
>   “stretching” your password hashes—repeatedly rehashing to obtain more
>   computationally intensive byte sequences. **If you rehash 100 times, a
>   dictionary attack that might otherwise take 1 month would take 8
>   years.**

So I implemented it this way!

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Password is 12345679");
byte[] hash = SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(data);
int temp=0;
while (temp < 100)
{
    hash = SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(hash);
    temp++;
}
```

Is the above code right? Will a dictionary attack really take 8 years or so to decipher?

Comment: I don't think that "do SHA512 100 times" has been subject to any sort of rigorous cryptanalysis that would discover potential shortcuts [which would erase the benefit of doing this] - you might be better off with something like bcrypt or PBKDF2. In any case, you should store the result of SHA512.Create() in a variable - calling it repeatedly may make it take longer, but it's not something the attacker has to do.

Comment: Thats dificult to say. You can also try asking at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might want to try http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ as well, in case you are interested in the algorithms and the scientific basis of their design.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the absence of shortcuts (as noted by @Random832), one should expect it to take 100x as long to brute-force test something that has been hashed 100 times as one. If the attacker is looking at every sequence of characters looking for a hash that matches, then anything that makes that hash take longer is going to slow him down (or equivalently, use more computing power).

Continuing to steal from Random832, this is a "poor-man's stretching." It is adequate and useful, but if you have the PBKDF2 function available, that is preferred, since PBKDF2 is well-analyzed by cryptographers. In the strictest sense, your code above is a "Password Based Key Derivation Function" (PBKDF), but PBKDF2 is a specific one. EDIT: I'm not a C# developer by trade, but it does look like .NET includes a PBKDF2 function [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx).

Note the key phrase in the above text, though: "that might otherwise take 1 month." The writer is *assuming* it would take a month to do the first, and 8 years is approximately 100 months. If it would have taken 1 minute to perform a dictionary attack on the first, you should expect it to take about 1.5 hours to do so on the second. There is no magic "8 years" here. It's just 100x the first number, whatever that first number happens to be.

EDIT: One more thing to note about stretching. You should always salt before you stretch. Salting means you add a random series of bytes to the start of the password. You then encode that salt along with the hash result (the salt is not a secret). So rather than hashing "Password is 12345679", you would hash "deadbeefPassword is 12345679" and you would then send "deadbeef" in the clear along with the final result. The reason you do this is because people choose the same passwords all the time. So if the attacker works out the result of hashing "Passw0rd!" then he could just check that result against your hash. Much cheaper. Similarly, if he had both Alice and Bob's hashes, he could tell if they were the same or different. But with a random salt, you can't do that, since it is almost certain that Alice and Bob will have their data hashed with different salts.

Answer (score -1):

This is wrong, you are just doing another hash that has the same overall caracteristics as the initial hash.

Comment: thts not true.It gives new hash every time i rehash it!

Comment: I mean the hashing function H'(x) = H(H(H( ... 100 times ... H(x))))) has the same overall caracteristics as H...

Comment: It has the same characteristics, but it take 100 times longer to compute, which slows down dictionary and other brute-force attacks by exactly that multiple.

Comment: @Julien: not *all* the same characteristics. It has one different characteristic: it takes 100 times as long to perform the hashing. And so, any attack which relies on performing the same hashing will take 100 times as long to succeed. :)

Answer (score -4):

A good hacker would trick you into visiting a web site salted with any of a dozen exploits, use that as a toehold to get a keystroke logger installed on your machine, and then email himself a log of everything you type for the next month or two.  That hacker will have your password without difficulty.